# AdMob not showing ads in iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I am trying to use AdMob on an app (built for iOS 4.0)

I've added the sample code available in the tutorial http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html which is the following (I've changed the adUnitID):

```
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                        self.view.frame.size.height -
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"XYZ";

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView_];

GADRequest * request = [GADRequest request];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Doing this nothing happens, no ad is shown and the number of requests in my AdMob app page increase erratically (i.e.: I can't seem to notice a pattern), but the most important is no ad is shown.

If I add the following code:

```
GADRequest * request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                               // Simulator
                       nil];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

I get the "Success! You are now ready to travel through the App Galaxy" default banner, but only this one.

So my questions are:

- Aren't the sample code enough to show ads? Why I never see an ad with the sample code?
- As far as I understood, requests mean the number of times my app asked for an ad to be shown. I also understood that not every request is replied with an ad (otherwise the fill rate would be 100%), but still, I NEVER saw an ad, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
  GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       self.view.frame.size.height -
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];//Set Position

  bannerView.adUnitID = @"12331255421245";//Call your id

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.


bannerView.rootViewController = self;

[self.view addSubview:bannerView];//Your attempt to add bannerview


// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.

[bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I set all above methods. Ad banner looks properly in Device but not showing ad in Simulator.

I set device Id as  GAD_SIMULATOR_ID.but it doesnt work. Its delegate methods are not being called.  !!

Answer (score -3):

Try it in the device. Apps in simulator don't show Admob ads.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar difficulties, and the device is no better. Another suggestion?

Comment: Check whether you've registered an adUnitID which is valid. If you've then place it as:
    `GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height - GAD_SIZE_320x50.height - 42, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
    bannerView.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_AD_ID;`
If you haven't register one. The entry point is probably here: http://www.admob.com/register

Comment: Eventually it was the lag you get when you run a new unit id. I had it again a few days later since no one used the app, but now that it's active, the ads show up.

Comment: @rushafi It does actually show up ads in the simulator.